# What is the correct and most common noun to describe the degree of how much a system of equations is underdetermined?

Tags: terminology, systems-of-equations

What is the correct and most commonly used noun to describe the degree of how much a system of equations is underdetermined? In my context the ratio $\frac{\text{number of equations}}{\text{number of variables}}$ is very important.

I already asked the question on [stackexchange's English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348068/is-there-a-word-for-the-degree-of-how-much-a-system-of-equations-is-underdetermi), but it didn't lead to a clear result.

The remaining filtered candidates so far are:

- (under)determinancy
- (under)determinacy
- (under)determinedness

Other suggestions welcome!

Comment: Maybe you have enough input to pick one yourself? It seems the other thread gave you everything you need. Sometimes, there is not going to be a 100% perfect phrase. But calling it the **determinacy** of a system seems to fit the meaning of "overdetermined", or **determinacy ratio**, or instead using the terminology **degrees of freedom** as the other thread said. I don't see that any answers could add to this.

Comment: A related expression is *rank deficiency*, which also covers the case of non-independent equations. Among your three proposals, only underdeterminacy seems valid. One could also think of just *fullness*.

Comment: @6005 I am not a native speaker. So it's difficult for me to judge. Especially I am confused about the last *n* in *determinaNcy* which some natives like to cut. What is grammatically correct? So either of the 3 would be fine for you? No preference?

Comment: @Rob OK! Fair enough. I will leave it to someone else to answer then.